# Flutter 'google_sign_in' build failed with GTMAppAuth issues - Undefined symbol _GTMBridgeAssetValid

Tags: xcode, flutter

I couldn't build iOS app if I added google_sign_in package.

If I try to build project on Flutter stable channel, then I got Error output from Xcode build:
XCode output

> Link GTMAppAuth (armv7) 0.1 seconds
> Ld /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdrpdvvoklyybneytvtgveizdgsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/GTMAppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Binary/GTMAppAuth
> normal armv7 (in target 'GTMAppAuth' from project 'Pods')
> cd /Users/.../Documents/cardaji/ios/Pods
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
> -target armv7-apple-ios9.0 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk
> -L/Users/lucky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdrpdvvoklyybneytvtgveizdgsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GTMAppAuth
> -F/Users/lucky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdrpdvvoklyybneytvtgveizdgsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GTMAppAuth
> -F/Users/lucky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdrpdvvoklyybneytvtgveizdgsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth
> -F/Users/lucky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdrpdvvoklyybneytvtgveizdgsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher
> -filelist /Users/lucky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdrpdvvoklyybneytvtgveizdgsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/GTMAppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTMAppAuth.LinkFileList
> -install_name @rpath/GTMAppAuth.framework/GTMAppAuth -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker
> /Users/lucky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdrpdvvoklyybneytvtgveizdgsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/GTMAppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTMAppAuth_lto.o
> -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/lucky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdrpdvvoklyybneytvtgveizdgsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GTMAppAuth
> -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Security -weak_framework AuthenticationServices -framework AppAuth -framework Foundation
> -framework GTMSessionFetcher -framework Security -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/lucky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdrpdvvoklyybneytvtgveizdgsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/GTMAppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTMAppAuth_dependency_info.dat
> -o /Users/lucky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdrpdvvoklyybneytvtgveizdgsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/GTMAppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Binary/GTMAppAuth
>
> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_GTMBridgeAssertValidSelector", referenced from:
>       -[GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization authorizeRequest:delegate:didFinishSelector:] in
> ```
>
> GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.4
```

flutter doctor

> ```
> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021 darwin-x64,
>     locale en)
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
> [✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
> [✓] Connected device (1 available)
> ```

pod install

```
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Downloading dependencies
Installing AgoraRtcEngine_iOS (3.3.2)
Installing AppAuth (1.4.0)
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.7)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit (11.0.1)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit_Basics (11.0.1)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit (11.0.1)
Installing FMDB (2.7.5)
Installing Firebase (8.0.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth (8.0.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (8.0.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (8.2.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestore (8.0.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (8.2.0)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (8.0.0)
Installing FirebaseStorage (8.0.0)
Installing Flutter (1.0.0)
Installing GTMAppAuth (1.2.2)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.6.0)
Installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (8.5.0)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (8.2.0)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (9.0.1)
Installing GoogleSignIn (5.0.2)
Installing GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (2.0.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.4.1)
Installing PromisesObjC (1.2.12)
Installing Toast (4.0.0)
Installing VoxImplantSDK (2.36.2)
Installing VoxImplantWebRTC (78.5.1)
Installing abseil (0.20200225.0)
Installing agora_rtc_engine (3.3.3)
Installing app_tracking_transparency (0.0.1)
Installing assets_audio_player (0.0.1)
Installing assets_audio_player_web (0.0.1)
Installing audioplayers (0.0.1)
Installing cloud_firestore (2.3.0)
Installing firebase_auth (1.4.1)
Installing firebase_core (1.3.0)
Installing firebase_messaging (10.0.3)
Installing firebase_storage (8.1.3)
Installing flutter_facebook_auth (2.0.0)
Installing flutter_local_notifications (0.0.1)
Installing flutter_notification_channel (0.0.1)
Installing flutter_voximplant (3.0.0)
Installing fluttertoast (0.0.2)
Installing gRPC-C++ (1.28.2)
Installing gRPC-Core (1.28.2)
Installing google_mobile_ads (0.0.1)
Installing google_sign_in (0.0.1)
Installing image_picker (0.0.1)
Installing in_app_purchase (0.0.1)
Installing leveldb-library (1.22.1)
Installing minimize_app (0.0.1)
Installing nanopb (2.30908.0)
Installing path_provider (0.0.1)
Installing permission_handler (5.1.0+2)
Installing record_mp3 (0.0.1)
Installing shared_preferences (0.0.1)
Installing sqflite (0.0.2)
Installing video_player (0.0.1)
Installing wakelock (0.0.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 30 dependencies from the Podfile and 60 total pods installed.
```

Comment: Try deleting the pod file and podlock file manually then running the app, let me know the result for further assistance.

Comment: I've deleted pod file and podlock file, and then flutter clean, pod install. but faliled to build with the same issue.

Comment: Have your configured google_sign_in for iOS properly? refer here if you haven't: https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in#ios-integration

Comment: yes. I've had configured it according to the iOS integration guide from step1 to step7 ( GoogleService-Info.plist and Info.plist ). Also I've congifured it for sign_in_with_apple. But also failed to build with the same issue( undefined symbol:_GTMBridgeAssetValidSelector ).
It was worked for Flutter stable version 1.22 and firebase old version packages.

Comment: have you enabled  google signin on the firebase authentication method section?

Comment: I don't think it's an error with the newer version as mine works completely fine .

Comment: google signin is enabled on the firebase auth method section.

Comment: I've added "pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', '= 1.5.0'" in Podfile, and then could build ios project successfully.

Comment: It seems like your problem is solved ! congratulations and thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've failed to build the iOS app with GTMSessionFetcher 1.6.0.
So I had to downgrade it to 1.5.0 manually by editing Podfile.
I've added the following line into Podfile, and then run "pod install" and built the project again, which is worked.

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', '= 1.5.0'  # add this line.
end
```

I found the last version of GTMSessionFetcher is 1.6.1.
But couldn't build with

> pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', '= 1.6.1'